# R timezone GMT and CET convert Unix timestamp

Tags: r

I got a Unix timestamp from a GMT-based database which I want to convert to datetime format. I use R in Germany.
Unix timestamp from GMT-based database: 1525732148

I convert it with:

```
install.packages("anytime")
library(anytime)
anytime(as.numeric(as.character(1525732148)))
```

Why do I get same date time, independent of system-date?

```
anytime(as.numeric(as.character(1525732148, tz="GMT")))
anytime(as.numeric(as.character(1525732148, tz="CET")))
```

Both give me as result: "2018-05-07 22:29:08 UTC"

I expected different results, because of different timezones.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is as follows:

```
> as.character(1525732148, tz="GMT")
[1] "1525732148"
```

This is what `anytime` gets as input. The `tz` parameter is supposed to be passed to `anytime`, not to `as.character`, which swallows without warning any additional parameters it does not recognise. Try `anytime(1525732148, tz="GMT")`.

```
> anytime::anytime(1525732148, tz="GMT")
[1] "2018-05-07 22:29:08 GMT"
> anytime::anytime(1525732148, tz="CET")
[1] "2018-05-08 00:29:08 CEST"
```

See: [`anytime`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/anytime/versions/0.3.0/topics/anytime)